# Переменные которые не обнуляются после закрытия приложения

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Здравствуйте как сделать так чтобы некоторые переменные не обнулялись при закрытии приложения на смартфоне,то есть мне нужно чтобы я присвоил значение переменной и когда мое приложение закроется и заново откроется эта переменная равнялась тому значению которое я присвоил

Comment: запись в файл и чтение из него при старте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без всякой лишней возни для этого подходит инструмент [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Сохраняет пары ключ-значение.

[Официальный туториал от гугла](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).